# Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory Unable to init server:

Tags: bash, terminal, directory, window, embedded-linux

I have installed ubuntu terminal in window 10. It's work fine but when I install gedit or any other application then these applications installed successfully but I can not open it. Whenever I tried it gives me the Error mentioned below.

[image]

> "Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
>   Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>   (gedit:4821): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"

Comment: Are you trying while having root access?

Comment: I am asking because this seems so very related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/817902/unable-to-open-any-graphical-app-with-sudo

Answer (score 2):

In the description of "Ubuntu terminal", it says: "run Ubuntu command line utilities". `gedit` is not a command line utility. It is a graphical utility, so it is not supported out of the box.

Your hope is that the final error is `cannot open display`. I bet that if you provide a suitable display in your computer, the utility will show up. Search for a X-server for your windows machine and try with the X-server installed.

This could help: https://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/